# Active users on a given date in a Month in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, cumulative-frequency

I am working to get cumulative distinct count of uids on daily basis. My dataset consists dates and UserIDs active on that date. Example : Say there are 2 uids (235,2354) appeared on date 2022-01-01 and they also appeared on next day with new uid 125 (235,2354,125) on 2022-01-02 At this point i want store cumulative count to be 3 not 5 as (user id 235 and 2354 already appeared on past day ).

My Sample Data looks like as follows:

https://github.com/manish-tripathi/Datasets/blob/main/Sample%20Data.xlsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asmys.png)

and my output should look as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn70P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way that seems to work, using your linked Excel sheet as the data source.

Create a new table:

```
Table 2 = DISTINCT('Table'[Date])
```

Add the columns:

```
MAU = CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[User ID]),
    'Table'[Date] <= EARLIER('Table 2'[Date]))

DAU = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[User ID]),
    'Table'[Date] = EARLIER('Table 2'[Date]))
```

***Result** from your Excel data*
[image]

Comment: I used a separate calendar table for date but I am getting the following error in doing so. "EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist."

Comment: @ManishTripathi Then do it the way **I** demonstrated.

Comment: Tried doing that way too still Getting same error

Comment: Clearly it works with the data you provided on your Excel sheet as evidenced by the results I show. Either the data you provided is not truly representative of your "real" data, or there is an issue with how you implemented my solution.  In my solution ```Table``` refers to the original data table in your worksheet. ```Table 2``` is the new table. And `[Date]` is the name of the column containing the Dates.